# set struts hashmap value in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, hashmap, struts, pojo

The below js code does not set the value to hashmap.

POJO:

```
private HashMap myMap = new HashMap();
public String getHashmapField(String key) {

    return (String) myMap.get(key);
}

public void setHashmapField(String key, String val) {
    myMap.put(key, val);
}
```

jsp field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hashmapField(lastname)" name="hashmapField(lastname)" />
```

js code:

```
document.getElementById("hashmapField(lastname)").value = "XYZ";
```

Comment: You can't set a hashmap value in JS untill you get it from the server.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember you should use special tags to set values.

https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/hidden-tag.html

in this case:

```
<s:hidden name="foo" value="%{hashmapField}" />
```

I don't know how you set the object that has hashmapField so I can't say if it needs to be prefixed but check the documentation and see if this is what you need.

The code that you have, unless things have changed a lot, doesn't actually use any properties from the server. At the very least I would expect %{...}